# Unable to load workspace - xcodebuild error.

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, xcodebuild

I'm trying to build my application on the server using the following command:

```
xcodebuild -workspace "MyWorkspace.xcworkspace" -scheme "MyScheme" archive -archivePath /tmp/build/App.xcarchive
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
 xcodebuild[803:1007] WARNING: Timed out waiting for <IDEWorkspace, 0x7ff3133b2420>/"finishedLoading" (300.002668 seconds elapsed)
2014-03-26 14:52:28,620 - appunite.node.ssh.SshConnection - INFO - xcodebuild: error: Unable to load workspace 'MyWorkspace.xcworkspace'; timeout occurred.
```

What could be causing this error?